# How to build a neural network in google colab using tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I am beginning with neural network and I am trying to build a neural network which counts red shape dots in an image.

I already have a set of 1000 images which look like this:

[image: The image I am working with]

I have them all stored in a folder all follow the same pattern `im_{number of the image}.png`, associated with each image I have a dictionary which follow the structure:

`{key: "im_{number of image}, value: "number of dots in the image"}`,

I am trying to build the database in TensorFlow where each image it's label is the number of dots in the game but I can't get it right.

I tried to use

```py
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory
```

but I don't know how to pass the dictionary to the labels parameter.

Also, to build the model,how do I composite the layers to get at the end the number of points in the image, do I need to have as many layers as maximum points can be in the image?

Any help would be appreciated :/.

Answer (score 0):

According to TensorFlow [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) for the `image_dataset_from_directory` method, you can either specify the labels as label argument or structure your directory in sub-directories (each one for each class, i.e. number of points).

In case you want to go with the first option, you need to extract the labels in alphabetical order of the key. For instance, you could:

```
my_dict = {"im_10":7, "im_8": 5, "im_17":6}
my_list_sorted = sorted(my_dict.items()) 
labels = list(zip(*my_list_sorted))[1]
```

Then you can use labels as argument for `image_dataset_from_directory`

Regarding the model, you can try different architectures from dense to convolutional layers. There is no fixed rule for the number and size of layers